# Can anyone tell me why there is iteration of the object I've created?

Tags: python, iterator

Im new in Python and at this time I'm leaning about iterators and iterables.Can anyone tell me why when i run this code the program prints out numbers until infinity ?my main question is why the object i made ,iterates in the for loop?which is the "item" in the obj1 that iterates?when i say for item in [1,2,3] i know that each time in each iteration the item is the number of the list but here ?Thanks a lot for your help cause im very comfused..

```
class Inter:
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value = value

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    count = self.value
    self.value +=1
    return count


obj1 = Inter(1)
for item in obj1:
   print(item)
```

Comment: To get the iteration to stop, you need to `raise StopIteration` in your `.__next__()` method when you reach the end (however "the end" might be defined in your case - it's not obvious from the code you posted when you might want it to end).

Comment: @jasonharper i appreciate it your answer but that's not the problem im dealing with .my question which is the item in obj1 that iterates in for loop? In the line "for item in obj1:print(item) whats happening and prints out all the numbers ?what is the item that keeps on repeating?

Comment: Your object is continuously being asked for the `__next__` item until it raises a `StopIteration`. That's what an iterator does.

Comment: The values produced by iteration are whatever your `.__next__()` method returns - the increasing value of `self.value`, in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop always calls `iter` to get an iterator for `obj1`. Roughly speaking, the loop is the same as

```
obj_iter = iter(obj1)  # obj_iter = obj1.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        item = next(obj_iter)  # item = obj_iter.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(item)
```

`obj_iter` is the return value of `obj1.__iter__` (so `obj1` itself).

`next(obj_iter)` is the return value of `obj_iter.__next__()`. Your `__next__` method never raises `StopIteration`; it *always* returns some new value.

To demonstrate the use of `StopIteration`, consider a slight modification that only produces the finite stream of values less than 10:

```
  def __next__(self):
    count = self.value
    if count >= 10:
        raise StopIteration
    self.value +=1
    return count
```

---

A few notes:

1. An instance of `Inter` is iterable because `__iter__` is defined. An iterable is something that knows how to make or get an iterator.
2. An instance of `Inter` is an iterator because `__next__` is defined. An iterator is something that knows how to produce the next value from an iterable.
3. All iterator types can (and by convention should) be made iterable as well
   by defining `__iter__ = lambda self: self`: an iterator itself is iterable
4. Not all iterable types are iterators, though. `list.__iter__` does not
   return the list; it returns an instance of `list_iterator`. That instance keeps a reference to the original list and maintains its own state
   for the definition of `list_iterator.__next__` to use.

Comment: thank you a lot !now its more clear to me cause it was very confusing at the beginning.one last question only..that means than each time in each iteration the iterator is the same object itself (obj1)??

Comment: Correct. The `for` loop gets the iterator *once* before iteration actually begins.